# Disable the history of browser's back button when right clicked on it

Tags: javascript

As you can see in the image below, I'm not interested in just disabling the `click` on the back button of the browser. Instead, I want to disable `right click` on it too. This is one point.

[image: Screenshot of Chrome history-back button]

The other part of the question is: How do Gmail handles the same feature. For example, if you login and perform certain actions on some of your mails, in browser's history log, it still maintans every single page which you have used and then you logout of it. Now, if you move on to the browser's history as I did in the image, it shows which all pages you visited but if you click on any one of it, it redirects to the login page. Now, my questions is, "How to handle the clicks on the same (when we get that history)?"

I have read about `window.history()`, `history.pushState()`. But they all helped me till handling the back button but not its right click.

Comment: when it says "enter image description here", SO doesn't suggest a description, it actually asks you to enter a one ;)

Comment: Disabling core browser functions like the back button is not very user friendly. Please don't. Regarding Gmail, it redirects you to the login page *because you're not currently logged in*, which has nothing to do with the history of things you did before you logged out.

Comment: Okay. Then @nnnnnn, you are saying that a session is been maintained on top of the browser's history. Right?